# How to scale image to center in CircledImageView

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a `CircledImageView` inside a layout, and have set android:src="@drawable/ic_some_icon" , but I don't find a way to center the image source.

```
 <android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_some_icon"
    app:circle_color="@color/red"
    app:circle_padding="@dimen/circle_padding"
    app:circle_radius="@dimen/circle_radius"
    app:circle_radius_pressed="@dimen/circle_radius_pressed"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is true when parent is a `LinearLayout` or similar:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>;
```

Comment: I need to center it for `CircledImageView` not `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="centerInside" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this XML parameter:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```